# Installing EasyPHP and MySQL data with application files

Tags: php, mysql, windows

I wrote some code in PHP that uses a MySQL database. It run with EasyPHP for Windows. Now it's quite difficult to install these on another PC. I have to:

- Install EasyPHP
- Copy .php files in www directory
- Run the .sql file on PhpMyAdmin

How can I make the installation easier?

Comment: You cannot - its the only way of migration.

Comment: you might want to upload your files to a web server. Then people can access them via the internet.... welcome to 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Framework like http://www.appcelerator.com/ to bundle your code as standalone application.

Mind you, it only has PHP support, so you would need to switch to SQlite  or similar..